# After a Mark of Detection half-elf casts a spell using the Magical Detection trait, can they cast the trait's other spells before taking a long rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, racial-traits, eberron, half-elf

The [Variant Half-Elf: Mark of Detection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/half-elf#MarkofDetectionHalfElf), from *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* p. 40, replaces the PHB half-elf's Skill Versatility trait with several new traits, one of which is the Magical Detection trait (bold for emphasis mine):

> You can cast the *detect magic* and *detect poison and disease* spells
> with this trait. Starting at 3rd level, you can also cast the *see
> invisibility* spell with it. Once you cast any of these spells with
> this trait, you can’t cast **that spell** with it again until you
> finish a long rest. [...]

If you cast *detect magic* using that trait, does that mean you can still cast each of the other spells once before you finish a long rest (i.e. it only prevents you from casting *detect magic* again using the trait before then)?
Or does it mean you can't cast any of the spells from the trait (including the ones you haven't used yet) again until you finish a long rest?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Yes, you can still use the trait to cast other spells

The spell text clearly differentiates repeatedly between the *trait* and the *spells* that are cast with it.  If it intended to exclude *any* use of the trait before a long rest, it would have said "this trait" (or similar) instead of "that spell."  And if it intended to exclude use of the other spells, the word "that" in "that spell" wouldn't make any sense.

Thus, it restricts you from using the trait to cast *only the specific spell you cast* again until after a long rest.